# Gradle sync failed: Cause: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueReporter

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, repository, build.gradle

I've recently installed Android Studio 3.1.3, I downloaded Gradle v4.4 and Gradle plugin v3.1.3. My build.gradle looks as follow:

```
/ Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.metova.com/nexus/content/groups/public'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://nexus.xebialabs.com/nexus/content/groups/public'
    }
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
    }

    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    maven {
        url 'repo1.maven.org/maven2'

    }
    maven {
       url 'central.maven.org/maven2'
    }

    //google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.metova.com/nexus/content/groups/public'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://nexus.xebialabs.com/nexus/content/groups/public'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    //google()
    maven {
       url 'repo1.maven.org/maven2'

    }
     maven {
        url 'central.maven.org/maven2'
    }

}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

I'm using other repos because I can't access to jcenter(), either google(). When I sync Gradle project, all dependencies are downloaded without problems, but a error appear:

```
Unable to load class 'com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueReporter'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's
dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network 
connection timeout.) 
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</li><li>The
state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all
Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</li><li>Your project may
be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other
plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
/li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try
closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I have performed both actions and they do not work for me. Please help me, I'm just a Cuban programmer with a desire to learn.

Comment: updating to dexcount 0.8.2 fixes the issue with https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin/issues/234

Comment: But I'm not using dexcount. My build.gradle looks as follow:          dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}